# Content decode problem|trying extra pdf text

Tags: python, pdf, arabic, pypdf

**Hello, I suffer from a problem that I did not find a solution for, which is that when I open the pdf file in the browser, it works fine and the Arabic text language is understandable, but when I try to extract the Arabic language through the pypdf library, the Arabic language is not understood this result from my firefox browser look good and no proplem**

[image]

**but when I try to extra the text using python  its look like this**:
[image]

I've tried various solutions like using utf8, latin1 and iso encoding

[image]
**here is my code:**

```
    from pypdf import PdfReader
    path=f'test.pdf'

    
    render=PdfReader(path,strict=False)

    for page in render.pages:
            text=page.extract_text()
            print(text)
```

**my file** [test.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QBufSE5JMeg5IjKEFY_6HsyClUxcohX-/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: The pdf file cannot be downloaded.

Comment: Have you tried other pdf readers? and do you get the same results? It doesn't appear to be a legacy 8-bit encoding. Possibly a corruption during font subsetting and embedding, especially if the font's cmap table was less than ideal?

Comment: @relent95 sorry here is the new link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QBufSE5JMeg5IjKEFY_6HsyClUxcohX-/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: That pdf file is using a non-standard font. You need to extract the font using a tool such as Mupdf, create a character mapping manually(maping a glyph index to a unicode character for each Arabic glyph), and convert characters.

Comment: @relent95, the font is Arial, so unlikely to be because of a non-standard font. More likely an artifact of how the font was subsetted. Also the mapping of Arabic glyphs to characters is a many-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the sample but as you show in your screenshot, the extractable text is NOT Arabic, it is poorly plain text encoded.

[image]

If we look with an editor for source characters we can see it IS Arabic but in wrong order as plain substituted Arial text.

[image]

Looking deeper we see it should be fairly well mapped for screen or printer generation.

`ABCDEE+Arial,Bold/Encoding/Identity-H/DescendantFonts[24 0 R]/ToUnicode 23 0 R`

However when we attempt to use Adobe Acrobat Export and apply Arial Arabic we can see it will not handle well.

[image]

So what might be possible ?

Normally I would suggest try PDFtotext but my current setups simply cannot show anything sensible for those areas.

[image]

Even if we were able to export by say, cut and paste, the major hurdle is that it seems it was stored as if a L2R (left to right) piece of text.

[image]

Even exporting as Word seems to have problems:

[image]

But that's a simple Find n Replace fix or select a better font:

[image]

the best export is as HTML but we are back to square one where the font **ff0** is a specialist Arabic output

[image]
[image]

**So in summary**

The only workable result I could find. Was since Adobe Acrobat "Export to office" was broken by that font, and so was Office Import from PDF. You need an alternative SDK / Editor (such as tracker PDFXedit) to "export" text as best as it can, from the PDF into Word or Excel, where some editing of the contents can be done programmatically. Ideally what is needed is to go back to the Luddite days of Typewritten text where it was simple plain text like this Courier layout.

[image]

The best way to mirror that in Modern day terms would be as HTML not PDF which is hysterically not suited to a mix of eastern and western directions at the same time. See how it misbehaves here when placed in HTML.

```
1 1023911001001 اﺑراھﯾم ﺣﯾدر طﺎﻟب ﻋﺑداﻟرﺿﺎ   94 91  85 93 85 88 85 82 ﻧﺎﺟﺢ  621
2 1023911001002 اﺑراھﯾم ﻣﺻطﻔﻰ ﻋرب ﺑداي       73 90  79 73 33 70 82 72 ﻣﻛﻣل   0 
3 1023911001003 اﺑراھﯾم ﻧﺷوان اﺑراھﯾم ﺧﻠﯾل   94 95  88 90 96 99 97 89 ﻧﺎﺟﺢ  659
4 1023911001004 اﺣﻣد اﯾﮭﺎب ﺟﻣﻌﮫ ﻏﺎﻟﻲ         96 98  99 87 92 97 96 78 ﻧﺎﺟﺢ  665
5 1023911001005 اﺣﻣد ﺳﻌدون ﺣﻣد ﺣﺳﯾن          90 97  92 98 89 88 99 80 ﻧﺎﺟﺢ  653
6 1023911001006 اﺣﻣد ﺻﺎﯾﻐن ﻋﻣر ﻣﺣﻣد          98 95  97 98 94 97 89 92 ﻧﺎﺟﺢ  668
7 1023911001007 اﺣﻣد ﻓراس ﺣﺎﺗم ﻋﻠﯾوي         97 100 96 81 79 64 95 82 ﻧﺎﺟﺢ  612
8 1023911001008 اﺣﻣد ﻗﺻﻲ ﺳﻌد وﺣﯾد            98 96  85 98 91 85 90 95 ﻧﺎﺟﺢ  643
9 1023911001009 اﺣﻣد ﻛرم ﻋﺻﺎم ﻋﺑداﻟرزاق      94 76  80 88 41 50 60 74 ﻣﻛﻣل   0
```

Comment: I am wondering why you are assuming that text can be extracted from a PDF? Under idea situations it can be, but those ideal situations are quite narrow. PDFs contain sequences of glyphs rather than characters. The cmap table in the font is parsed to create a toUnicode glyph to character mapping which is used to get text. This assumes that no sophisticated glyph substitutions and reordering isn't occurring in the rendering engines, and also assumes that the cmap table is accurate, and the font subsetting and embedding doesn't screw things up. There is always the ActualText attribute though.

Comment: 1) the characters in the string you give in your comment are from the Arabic Presentation Forms block rather than from the Arabic block. You would need to convert the back to the actual characters.  2) PDF glyph sequences are visually laid out (there is no logical ordering in a PDF).  Also the more sophisticated the font is, the more difficult it is to extract text. A simplified Naskh font would be much easier than a Nastaliq font.

Comment: For instance: `دﻣﺣﻣ رﻣﻋ` in your comment is U+062F U+FEE3 U+FEA3 U+FEE3 U+0020 U+0631 U+FEE3 U+FECB, reversed, and presentation forms.

Comment: I know the order is wrong, and I know the characters are wrong due to subsetting. PDF files contain glyph IDs not characters. ToUnicode mapping is used to get back to characters, but it can reorder characters, it can't handle complex glyph substitutions and glyph reordering. The best you can do is 1) try to map glyphs to characters, and 2) try to do a visual to logical conversion per line.

Comment: I get different results form different software, looking at one of teh column headers. PDF.js gives me 03F2 03E7 038E 03A3 0397 03E3 03FB 038D 0003 03E1 03D7 03AD 03DF; Preview: 10FC1E 10FC03 10FC02 10FC0F 10FC25 10FC13 10FC32 10FC07 0020 10FC10 10FC28 10FC05 10FC06 10FC07;  and acrobat reader 1003F2 1003E7 10038E 1003A3 100397 1003E3 1003FB 10038D 100003 1003E1 1003D7 1003AD 1003DF 10038D; Also reader indicates page extraction is disallowed.

Comment: I never expect to get meaningful text from PDFs in African, Middle eastern, Central Asian, South Asian, South East Asian and some Indigenous languages. That way, when I do, I can be presently surprised. And hand editing after extract is a pain. But sometimes necessary when the PDF contains more than one font. Any file format based on glyphs rather than characters is likely to cause problems at some point.

Comment: The more sophisticated the font, in terms of opentype features and rendering, the further the glyph streams move away from simple glyph to Unicode mapping. PDF was originally designed as a preprint format growing out of postscript. It was more about ink on paper, and position of glyphs relative to each other, than on characters. None of the enhancements to PDF standards over time changed that basic fact of PDFs.